# Fitting Large Matrix Calculations into Memory when using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am attempting to build a model which has two phases.
The first takes an input image and passes it through a conv-deconv network. The resulting Tensor has entries corresponding to pixels in a desired output image (same size as the input image).

To calculate the final output image I want to take the value generated at each pixel location from the first phase and use it as an additional input to a reduction function that is applied over the entire input image. This second step has no trainable variables, but it does have computation/memory costs that grow exponentially with the size of the input (each output pixel is a function of all input pixels).

I'm currently using the tf.map_fn to calculate the output image. I'm mapping the output pixel calculation function onto the results from the first phase. My desire is that tensorflow would allocate the memory to store the intermediate tensors needed for each pixel calculation and then free that memory before moving on to the next pixel calculation. But instead it seems to never free the intermediate calculations causing OOM errors.

Is there someway to tell tensorflow (either explicitly or implicitly) that  it should free the memory allocated to hold the data of a Tensor that is no longer needed in the calculation?

Comment: Are you partitioning your computation into multiple tensors? (ie, TensorFlow won't deallocate a part of a tensor object)

Comment: Yes. I did originally try to do giant matrix operations, but it makes more sense to me why that wasn't working. This is what led me to tf.map_fn() to create tensors for each individual pixel calculation.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow deallocates memory for the tensor as soon as the tensor is no longer needed for any future calculations. You can verify this by looking at memory deallocation messages as shown in this [notebook](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/notebooks/blob/master/mnist-memory.ipynb).

It's possible you are running out of memory because TensorFlow executes nodes in a memory inefficient order.

As an example, consider following computation:

```
k = 2000
a = tf.random_uniform(shape=(k,k))
for i in range(n):
    a = tf.matmul(a, tf.random_uniform(shape=(k,k)))
```

The order in which it is evaluated can be shown below

[image]

All the circles (`tf.random_uniform`) nodes are evaluated first, followed by squares (`tf.matmul`). This has `O(n)` memory requirement compared to `O(1)` for the optimal order.

You can use control dependencies to force a specific execution order, ie, using helper function as below:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.graph_editor as ge
def run_after(a_tensor, b_tensor):
    """Force a to run after b"""
    ge.reroute.add_control_inputs(a_tensor.op, [b_tensor.op])
```

Comment: Thanks, it's good to hear that if I can get dependencies right this should be taken care of automatically. In my case I'm using the map_fn so it doesn't seem immediately apparent to me how to force the operations to be done sequentially (setting parallel_iterations=1 didn't seem to solve my problem like I thought it would, btw). Does building a collection of output tensors created by the mapping function then stringing them together with dependencies as you suggested seem like the proper approach?

Comment: Hm, map_fn works on slices of tensors, it doesnt seem possible to deallocate memory for unneeded slices, why not use regular Python map?

Comment: That does make sense. I think I just reflexively tended towards using tensorflow ops, but I suppose it might be overkill. I'm not worried about the size of the inputs/outputs to tf.map_fn though, just the intermediate tensors generated within the mapping function (if that makes sense). In the python map case I would still need to build dependency chains though right?

Comment: When I pass a python function that builds a portion of a graph (and returns a Tensor) as the map_fn fn argument I assumed all tensorflow does is stamp down lots of instances of that graph structure connected to the tensor slices, right?

Comment: No, it's more efficient than that

Comment: OK, I will try python control then. Does my earlier statement about still requiring control dependencies make sense?

Comment: Yes you'll need control deps to force nodes to run in particular order